# getElementBy(Value?) need to check if element is clicked open(true) or closed(false)

Tags: excel, vba

How can I check if below line is true of false. It is the code of the element which opens or closed a filter list. If the filter is closed `value=false`, if the filter is opened `value=true`

HTML code of the element:

```
<div id="docTypeForm:filterPnl" class="rf-cp rf-tgp" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
     <input id="docTypeForm:filterPnl-value" name="docTypeForm:filterPnl-value" 
     type="hidden" value="true">
```

The value will appear as true of false. When i run the macro the first time it works because the drop down is default false, but the second time the drop down is true so my code fails at that point.

I check following codes:

```
    If obJIE.document.getElementById("docTypeForm:filterPnl-Value").Hidden = False Then
        MsgBox False
    Else
        MsgBox True '

    End If
```

```
 If obJIE.document.getElementById("docTypeForm:filterPnl-Value").Value= False Then
```

```
If obJIE.document.queryselector("input("True")") = False then
```

```
 If obJIE.document.getElementById("docTypeForm:filterPnl-Value").getAttribute("Value")= False Then
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the issues and what type of element you are referencing?  Possibly post the URL or the HTML?

Comment: The URL is an online private server, the first code is the HTML code of the element which I want to check. 
What do you mean with type of element? These are element in internet explorer